# How to find the class name of an element inside a button?

Tags: jquery, html, font-awesome, parent-child

I have an HTML button with a FontAwesome icon inside

```
    <button id='vabs'><i class="fa fa-eye"></i> <span>Show</span></button>
```

I am trying to get the class name of the `i` tag inside the `button` (fa-eye) by

```
     $('#vabs').click(function() {
   alert(this.children.className);});
```

This gives an undefined value. How do I achieve this?

Comment: you can use .attr('class');

Answer (score 2):

Obviously, there are other ways of doing that, but here are 2 of them:

1. Use `childNodes[0]` to get the first child of `#vabs`

```js
$("#vabs").on("click", function() {  
  let className = this.childNodes[0].className
  console.log(className)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id='vabs'><i class="fa fa-eye"></i> <span>Show</span></button>
```

2. Use just jQuery

```js
$("#vabs").on("click", function() {  
  let className = $(this).find("i").attr("class")
  console.log(className)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id='vabs'><i class="fa fa-eye"></i> <span>Show</span></button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this, `$(this).children().attr('class')` to get attribute class value, then use `split()` function:

```js
$('#vabs').click(function() {
   let classList = $(this).children().attr('class').split(" ");
   let classAttr = $(this).children().attr('class');
   console.log(classList);
   console.log(classAttr);
});
```

```html
<button id='vabs'><i class="fa fa-eye"></i> <span>Show</span></button>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```